# Make a page with the title formatted similarly to TOC, Chapter Page,Bibliography

Tags: formatting

For my thesis, I would like to create a page that is formatted similarly to pages like the TOC, Chapter Page(without "Chapter X"), or the Bibliography. That means that I don't want a header, and I want the title to look exactly like that too.
The background is that I need to make an abstract in two languages.
Under the titles (Abstract and Zusammenfassung) I plan to have a normal block of text. Does anybody know how to do this?
the documenttype is a report.
Thanks a lot!

With kind regards,
R.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you should be able to get such a page using `\chapter*{xxx}`.  if you would like something more detailed, please provide a small compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` to give potential helpers something to experiment with.

Comment: Well that was easy :-) Thanks a lot ! Only problem that remains is that these pages dont appear in my TOC.. I'll have to see what i can do about that.

Comment: it sounds like you're pretty new at this.  allow me to suggest some good reading material: a few books on the page http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/ of which the one entitled "Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis" might be particularly applicable.

Comment: @Rob To add the unnumbered chapter to the toc, you could try something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{xxx}` after `\chapter*{xxx}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right, I'm new at this and I have to say in comparison to MS Word this is rocket science, but its starting to work. Thanks a lot for the link and for the tip with \addcontentsline. Problem is now solved

Comment: @samcarter -- the thanks for pointing out `\addcontentsline` belongs to you, not me.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the ping and the shared thanks!

Comment: @Rob -- to me, latex has one thing in common with rocket science that ms word does not -- it's logical.  assigned the task of updating an ms word file, i become a destructive tester, often unable to get back safely to the starting point.